# Document Level Locking In MongoDb 4.2

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to read 10M documents out of 30M documents in one Thread and I do not want these 10M to get accessed by another thread while rest 20 million should be accessible.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Sohan I have tried to use transactions with repeatable read isolation but still, I am not able to acquire the exclusive lock kind of while reading documents.

Comment: And I have tried to use findAllAndRemove() but if service shutdowns after running this method and before processing records. Is it possible to rollback?